# Django select2 with autocomplete_fields to have a dynamic default value

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I have a `Product` model and a `HeadFlowDataset` model. These two models are connected with a foreinkey relationship, in which one `product` can have many `headflowdataset` pairs.

Their model codes are as below:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
    )
    ...
    # other fields in the model, not exactly related to this problem

class HeadFlowDataSet(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
    )
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    head = models.FloatField()
    flow = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.pump_name
```

Every product can have up to 10-15 head-flow sets. And currently I'm using Django admin panel to populate my product database. On the other hand, there may be up to 1000 products in total. So when the admin was trying to add head-flow datasets, the process was a bit challenging to find the product name from the select menu that Django admin provided. So I used Django `autocomplete_fields` in the ModelAdmin as below so that the admin can at least search for the product name:

```
class HeadFlowDatasetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        "product",
        "head",
        "flow",
    )
    fields = (
        "product",
        "head",
        "flow",
    )
    autocomplete_fields = ["product"]

    def get_ordering(self, request):
        return [Lower("product__pump_name"), "head"]
```

But this approach too is a bit frustrating to search for the product name every time we are trying to add a new head-flow dataset.

QUESTION:
How can I set a default value for this `select2` field that dynamically sets the last product searched as the default value? So that when the admin tries to add a new head-flow dataset, he sees the last product selected by default until he manually changes the product?

Comment: Why not use an inline so that you can add multiple HeadFlowDataSet to a product in one go from the product admin?

Comment: @IainShelvington I did some research about this inline tabular thing in Django admin and it was really cool and just what I needed. Thanks for the input

Comment: @Javad Please check the comment below your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a concept in Django called [**`InlineModelAdmin`** <sup>[django-docs]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) and in your case, your `admin.py` module can be as below:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from your_app_name.models import Product, HeadFlowDataSet


class HeadFlowDatasetInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = HeadFlowDataset
    extra = 1


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        "pump_name",
        "main_model",
        "usage",
        "pump_type",
    )
    search_fields = (
        "pump_name",
        "main_model__model_name_fa",
        "usage__usage_name_fa",
        "pump_type__type_name",
    )
    fields = (
        "main_model",
        "usage",
        "sub_usage",
        "pump_type",
        "pump_name",
        "pump_image",
        "NPSH_diagram_image",
        "power_diagram_image",
        "max_head",
        "max_flow",
        "motor_ph",
        "motor_rpm",
        "pump_technical_datasheet_fa",
        "pump_technical_datasheet_en",
    )
    inlines = [HeadFlowDatasetInline]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.created_by = request.user
        obj.last_updated_by = request.user
        obj.save()

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        instances = formset.save(commit=False)
        for instance in instances:
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
```

With the above code snippet, you have an inline part with one set of `HeadFlowDataset`objects on each page of your `Product` models in your Django admin panel which can be added on need form that panel and with this approach, this issue will be resolved.

Comment: This solution worked but there were a few modifications, I used this method according to the Django docs and it worked. Thanks for suggesting this solution. I'm not marking this solution as accepted, I'm suggesting an edit on your answer. Please confirm the edit (if needed) so that I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Vahid I approved your suggestion, thank you for your responsibility to contribute to the community.